# What the mysql query difference between =1 and = '1' with enum?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I had a query like

```
SELECT name, town FROM clients WHERE course = 1;
```

and it gave me some results.

But i noticed the query didn't output the latest entries. I look into the table clients with phpmyadmin and i saw more course fields with value 1.
After i changed the query to

```
SELECT name, town FROM clients WHERE course = '1';
```

i got the right output.

My question: why is this? and why did i get some results with the first query ?

ps: course is an enum field ( '0','1').

Comment: i believe without quotes you're querying TRUE, whilst with the quotes you're going for the exact match of '1'

Comment: tx user194292, i get that part but as my first query gave me results/output i didn't realise it was wrong. Apparently it gives an index back (see Marty McVry's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1` is either an integer value, or 'TRUE', or ... (ambiguous) while `'1'` is a string value.

As explained in the [MySQL-documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) for the ENUM-type:

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of
>   permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column
>   specification at table creation time.
>
> [...]
>
> If you wish to use a number as an enumeration value, you must enclose
>   it in quotation marks. If the quotation marks are omitted, the number
>   is regarded as an index. For this and other reasons—as explained later
>   in this section—we strongly recommend that you do not use numbers as
>   enumeration values.

So, ENUM is a string object, therefore you need to reference to it as a string.

Comment: ok that's clear but why did i get results/output with the first query? it stopped showing output after 31 results?? note2myself: don't use numbers as enumaration

Comment: It would compare to the value with index 1, being '0', I guess.